# Procedure Works Once

Tags: excel, vb.net, loops

I have a working code which reads data from the first excel file and copy and paste it into another file and then loops to read the same data in the other file and puts it underneath
My code works for the first file and copy and paste data correctly but it does not read the next file in the same way

So What Should I Do ??

My Code

```
            If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Directory = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim Files() As System.IO.FileInfo
            Dim DirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Directory)
            Files = DirInfo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            For Each File In Files
                Dim xl As New Excel.Application
                Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
                Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
                Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
                Dim Lastrow As Integer
                Dim Lrow As Integer
                Dim Frow As Integer
                Dim Crow As Integer
                Dim BMVal As String
                BMVal = cboBarMark.Text
                wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(File.FullName)
                wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\Patches\Main_Master.xlsm")
                Lastrow = wb1.Sheets("Master").Range("A65536").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
                For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                    If ws.Name = "SCHEDULE" Then
                        Lrow = ws.Range("A65536").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
                        Frow = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:="Bar mark", After:=ws.Range("B1")).Row
                        Crow = Lrow - Frow
                        Do While Len(File) > 0
                            Select Case BMVal
                                Case Is = "A"
                                    ws.Range("A1", "A" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "B"
                                    ws.Range("B1", "B" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "C"
                                    ws.Range("C1", "C" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "D"
                                    ws.Range("D1", "D" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "E"
                                    ws.Range("E1", "E" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "F"
                                    ws.Range("F1", "F" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "G"
                                    ws.Range("G1", "G" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "H"
                                    ws.Range("H1", "H" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "I"
                                    ws.Range("I1", "I" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "J"
                                    ws.Range("J1", "J" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "K"
                                    ws.Range("K1", "K" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Is = "L"
                                    ws.Range("L1", "L" & Crow).Offset(RowNo - 1, 0).Copy()
                                Case Else
                            End Select
                            wb1.Activate()
                            wb1.Sheets("Master").Range("B1").Value = "Bar Mark"
                            wb1.Sheets("Master").Range("B1", "B" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
                        Loop
                    End If
                Next
                wb.Close(SaveChanges:=vbTrue)
                wb1.Close(SaveChanges:=vbTrue)
                xl.Workbooks.Close()
                xl.Quit()
            Next
        End If
```

Thanks, Regards
Moheb Labib

Comment: You need to debug your code. You need to debug your code before you post here, not just read it. If you don't know how to debug, with breakpoints, then you need to learn now.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019 ... there is either an error occurring or something in your logic doing something you didn't expect. Either way, you are in the best position to find out by stepping through the code with the debugger and evaluating what's actually taking place as it executes.

Comment: I'd start by moving this line, `wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\Patches\Main_Master.xlsm")`, to above and outside the `for` loop.  You'd need to move the declaration line up as well, obviously.

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks